# Linux forgot password

Tags: password

I forgot the password for my Asus eee pc with linux operating system. How can I get back in without losing all of the files?

I found this http://blog.another-d-mention.ro/misc/eee-pc/reset-system-password-for-eeepc/

Do you believe every model of a linux version has BusyBox, the commands should work for every model (not just Eee PC 701, Eee PC 904 HD, Eee PC 900 that's what they talk about in the link) and it should not damage the system?

If it doesn't work, what are the alternatives?

Comment: What Linux distribution? Which password did you lose: your personal or root?

Answer (score 1):

Boot up on a USB-stick or cdrom and select the "Recovery mode" (Ubuntu or Debian has that). When you get to the prompt, you can change the password for root:

```
passwd root
```

or for an other user:

```
passwd joe
```